# segfault when using sizeof(vector[0]) * vector->size()

Tags: c++, opengl, stl

Given the working code snippet

```
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices->size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices->front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Set the size and data of our VBO and set it to STATIC_DRAW
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); // Set up our vertex attributes pointer


    glGenBuffers(1,&indexBufferId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,indexBufferId);
    // We have to use &triangles.front() otherwise we get vector house keeping garbage
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangles->size() * sizeof(unsigned), &triangles->front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Set the size and data of our VBO and set it to STATIC_DRAW
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); // Set up our vertex attributes pointer
```

basically I am sending data to OpenGL and naturally I have to tell it where to copy from, and how much to copy. After changing types on my vectors a few times I decided I didn't want to keep updating every type reference and tried the following line.

```
 glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangles->size() * sizeof(triangles[0]), &triangles->front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Set the size and data of our VBO and set it to STATIC_DRAW
```

using `sizeof(triangles[0])` instead of `sizeof(unsigned)`. Figuring hey my vector is typed so it should be able to figure the type of an element at compile time so I don't have to tell it each refactor.

However this is not the case. This single change causes a segfault when done to either line with their respective vector.

Another point of confusion (arose when trying to compact my code) is using

```
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangles->size() * sizeof(unsigned), &triangles[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

replacing `&triangles.front()` with `&triangles[0]` causes the same segfault. I was of the understanding that these two statements should be equal.

Where is my misunderstanding? I thought the statements which are segfaulting were equivalent to the working ones.

Comment: You probably mean sizeof((*vector)[0]). Either that or vector->size should be vector.size.

Comment: `glVertexAttribPointer` is used for setting up attribute data. It is *not* used for setting up your index data for `glDrawElements` calls. That is done purely by binding to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` and calling `glDrawElements` or its variations. In your case, the call is redundant, so it does no harm. But you still shouldn't do it.

Comment: @luiscubal: You should probably post that as an answer, since it's what is wrong.

Comment: That does explain that portion of my misunderstanding. But it seems like the type of vector[0] should be type T

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, the second call to VertexAttrib was a copy paste error. Got distracted by this syntax.

Comment: `&triangles.front()` is the address of the iterator.  `&(*triangles.front())` would be of the element,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using vector->size(), that means vector must be a pointer(unless you are using some operator overloading magic).

Although vector does have operator [], vector*[] will not behave as you expect it to.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    vector<int>* x = new vector<int>();
    x->push_back(3);
    x->push_back(4);

    cout << sizeof(vector<int>*) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(x) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(vector<int>) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(*x) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(x[0]) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(int) << endl;
    cout << sizeof((*x)[0]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, that program outputs this:

```
8
8
24
24
24
4
4
```

In other words, `sizeof(vector[0])` will give you the size of `vector`, not the size of each vector element.
And since the size calculation is wrong, segmentation fault issues are expected.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the declaration of `triangles`, but from how you use it it seems to be `std::vector<unsigned>*` (note the pointer). With that in mind, it should be:

```
sizeof( (*triangles)[0] )
```

and

```
&(*triangles)[0]
```